# Creating an online javascript survey with a reject state for bad answers

Tags: javascript, survey

I am thinking about creating an online javascript survey as a quiz for my students. I would like this survey to be similar to those people take when trying to qualify for a market research study (ie it fails the user if they get one answer that doesn't meet the criteria for the study, and it continues the survey if they qualify to that point). If I implement this, is there a way that my students could determine the appropriate answer to select to ensure that they get all of the right answers and never hit the reject page?

Comment: If you're doing this purely in JavaScript (i.e. no server side processing) then yes, it could be reverse engineered fairly easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All JavaScript is provided to the browser as plain text and can easily be viewed by the user (In this case your students). That means that any instructions you give the webpage can be seen by the user; which in essence means you give them the right answers in the code (If they are smart enough to find it). The only way to truly hide the answers from them would be to process their answers out of the browser.

Comment: Very true.  In fact, even if you put the part of the code that measures the answers in a script that you downloaded at runtime, a clever user could find that in the code and download the script first.  There's absolutely no way to secure the answers in-browser.  You'd have to use something like PHP where you loaded just the answer score or result (which is processed out of browser).